# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast

Tags: java, hibernate

When i click on login, it checks the DB if there is a value matching then i get this error, else it does print me **null**.

```
public Login authenticate(Login login) {
         String query = "SELECT 1 FROM Login AS l WHERE l.email=? AND l.password=?";
         Object[] parameters = { login.getEmail(), login.getPassword() };
         List resultsList = getHibernateTemplate().find(query,parameters);
         if (resultsList.isEmpty()) {            
         }
         else if (resultsList.size() > 1) {

         }
         else {
           Login login1 = (Login) resultsList.get(0);
           System.out.println("Hello" + login1);
           return login1;
         }       
       return null;  
}
```

Error below

> Cause: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   com.intermedix.domain.Login
>           at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:507)
>           at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
>           at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.fireEvent(AbstractComponent.java:1154)
>           at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:371)
>           at com.vaadin.ui.Button.changeVariables(Button.java:193)
>           at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.handleVariables(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:1094)
>           at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.doHandleUidlRequest(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:590)
>           at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.CommunicationManager.handleUidlRequest(CommunicationManager.java:266)
>           at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:476)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:943)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>           at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
>           at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   com.intermedix.domain.Login
>           at com.intermedix.services.LoginService.authenticate(LoginService.java:34)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:301)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>           at $Proxy32.authenticate(Unknown Source)
>           at com.intermedix.ui.LoginDailog.checkLogin(LoginDailog.java:106)
>           at com.intermedix.ui.LoginDailog.access$0(LoginDailog.java:102)
>           at com.intermedix.ui.LoginDailog$1.buttonClick(LoginDailog.java:52)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:487)
>           ... 26 more

Comment: I'd possibly take the time to re-read about the Hibernate query language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you want to `SELECT l` (L-letter) rather than `SELECT 1` (the number 1)? When you select a number, the number is returned. Hence the `Integer`

Or if this `1` is meant to be the limit, then use `query.setMaxResults(1)`

Comment: No, he just needs SELECT FROM, same as his last question.

Comment: well, technically he can only use `FROM Login` ;)

Comment: I changed my query into String query = "SELECT L FROM Login AS L WHERE L.email=? AND L.password=?"; and it worked.... Thats Bozho always there to help

Answer (score 1):

your List should be of Login

```
List<Login> resultList = (getHibernateTemplate().find(query,parameters);
```

then, when you make this:

```
Login login1 = (Login) resultsList.get(0);
```

you'll be getting an Instance of Login, and will not be trying to cast anything, but the Object Login to itself.